# Can't get $(window).load() to work on a page loaded into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load, onload

Forgive me, I'm new to this.

I have a collection of .html files and depending on which is selected I'm having it load into a div on a page, sort of like an iframe. I can get this all working fine, but my problem is with window onload events. I can get onload working on the main page, but the onload events included on the pages loaded into the div on the main page do not work, whether I write it into the .html file or call it from an external file. $(document).ready works, but I'm trying to make sure the javascript is loaded after everything else.

Basically I don't know how to get window onload working on a page loaded into a div.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: This would load one of the external pages into the main one:

```
$('div#socket').load('pages/' + thisTab + '.html');
```

where thisTab would be the name of one of the files and also the tab selected.

and something like this would be at the bottom of one of the loaded pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
alert('1');
});

$(window).load(function(){
alert('2');
});
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   alert('3');
});
</script>
```

I only get the '1' to be alerted.

Comment: you should not use `<script>` tag in loaded pages, it will just confuse you. run scripts from main page

Comment: other option is to bind event  like 'my_load' to one of the elements of the loaded page, in callback trigger that event

Comment: _"Basically I don't know how to get window onload working on a page loaded into a div."_ - You're not loading a _page_ into a div per se, at least not in the sense of embedding an independent page with its own window and its own window load event. You're adding elements/text to a div on the _current_ page, for which the _window_ load event has already happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this having scripts inside the loaded page demo:

in loaded page:

```
<script id="loader_script" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert('1');
});

$('loader_script').one('my_load',function(){
  alert('2');
});
</script>
```

in main script:

```
var innerpage=$('div#socket');
innerpage.load('pages/' + thisTab + '.html',function(){
     innerpage.find('#loader_script').trigger('my_load');
});
```

Comment: This is closer to what I was trying to do with my convoluted setup. Something about this code isn't working, but I stuck all the stuff I wanted to load into a function and stuck the function at the bottom of the loaded page and used the callback on the main page to load it.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you are looking for an option to execute something once you load some content to the main page (using ajax). You may use the **callback** function of the ajax loading method.

```
$("#DivInsideMainPage").load("remotepage.html",function(){
   alert("This will execute only after loading the partial content") 
   //Execute the fancy code you want here    
});
```

Comment: This is very straightforward. Thank you. What I failed to specify is that the code I need to run is different for each page. Initially I used the same variable and $.getScript to load the javascript, but I noticed a delay causing some pop-in glitches, or whatever you'd call them. If I could up vote the two of you I would.